# C++/CLI HTTP Proxy problems

Tags: proxy, c++-cli

I'm trying(very hard) to make a small HTTP Proxy server which I can use to save all communications to a file. Seeing as I dont really have any experience in the area, I used a class from codeproject.com and some associated code to get started (It was made in the old CLI syntax, so I converted it). I couldn't get it working, so I added lots more code to make it work (threads etc), and now it sort of works. Basically, it recieves something from a client (I just configured Mozilla Firefox to route its connections through this proxy) and then routes it to google.com. After it sends Firefox's data to google, recieves a responce, and sends that to Firefox. This works fine, but then the proxy fails to recieve any data from Firefox. It just loops in the Sleep(50) section. Anyway, heres the code:

**ProxyTest.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "CHTTPProxy.h"

public ref class ClientThread {
public:
    System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient ^ pClient;
    CHttpProxy ^ pProxy;
    System::Int32 ^ pRecieveBufferSize;
    System::Threading::Thread ^ Thread;
    ClientThread(System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient ^ sClient,
                 CHttpProxy ^ sProxy,
                 System::Int32 ^ sRecieveBufferSize) {
        pClient = sClient;
        pProxy = sProxy;
        pRecieveBufferSize = sRecieveBufferSize;
    };
    void StartReading() {
        Thread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this,&ClientThread::ThreadEntryPoint));
        Thread->Start();
    };
    void ThreadEntryPoint() {
        char * bytess;
        bytess = new char[(int)pRecieveBufferSize];
        memset(bytess, 0, (int)pRecieveBufferSize);
        array<unsigned char> ^ bytes = gcnew array<unsigned char>((int)pRecieveBufferSize);
        array<unsigned char> ^ sendbytes;
        do {
            if (pClient->GetStream()->DataAvailable) {
                try {
                    do {
                        Sleep(100); //Lets wait for whole packet to get cached (If it even does...)
                        unsigned int k = pClient->GetStream()->Read(bytes, 0, (int)pRecieveBufferSize); //Read it
                        for (unsigned int i=0; i<(int)pRecieveBufferSize; i++) bytess[i] = bytes[i];
                        Console::WriteLine("Packet Received:\n"+gcnew System::String(bytess));
                        pProxy->SendToServer(bytes,pClient->GetStream()); //Now send it to google!

                    } while (pClient->GetStream()->DataAvailable);
                } catch (Exception ^ e) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                Sleep(50);
                if (!(pClient->Connected)) break;
            };
        } while (pClient->GetStream()->CanRead);
        delete [] bytess;
        pClient->Close();
    };
};
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::Collections::Generic::Stack<ClientThread ^> ^ Clients =
        gcnew System::Collections::Generic::Stack<ClientThread ^>();

    System::Net::Sockets::TcpListener ^ pTcpListener = gcnew System::Net::Sockets::TcpListener(8080);

    pTcpListener->Start();
    System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient ^ pTcpClient;
    while (1) {
        pTcpClient = pTcpListener->AcceptTcpClient(); //Wait for client

        ClientThread ^ Client = gcnew ClientThread(pTcpClient,
                                gcnew CHttpProxy("www.google.com.au", 80),
                                pTcpClient->ReceiveBufferSize); //Make a new object for this client

        Client->StartReading(); //Start the thread
        Clients->Push(Client); //Add it to the list
    };
    pTcpListener->Stop();
    return 0;
}
```

**CHTTPProxy.h**, from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/howtoproxy.aspx with a lot of modifications:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <SYSTEM.DLL>
using namespace System;
using System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient;
using System::String;
using System::Exception;
using System::Net::Sockets::NetworkStream;
#include <stdio.h>

ref class CHttpProxy 
{ 
public: 
    CHttpProxy(System::String ^ szHost, int port); 
    System::String ^ m_host; 
    int m_port; 
    void SendToServer(array<unsigned char> ^ Packet, System::Net::Sockets::NetworkStream ^ sendstr); 
};

CHttpProxy::CHttpProxy(System::String ^ szHost, int port)
{
    m_host = gcnew System::String(szHost);
    m_port = port;
}

void CHttpProxy::SendToServer(array<unsigned char> ^ Packet, System::Net::Sockets::NetworkStream ^ sendstr)
{
    TcpClient ^ tcpclnt = gcnew TcpClient();

    try
    {
        tcpclnt->Connect(m_host,m_port); 
    }
    catch (Exception ^ e )
    {
        Console::WriteLine(e->ToString());
        return;
    }

    // Send it
    if ( tcpclnt )
    {
        NetworkStream ^ networkStream;

        networkStream = tcpclnt->GetStream();

        int size = Packet->Length;        
        networkStream->Write(Packet, 0, size);
        array<unsigned char> ^ bytes = gcnew array<unsigned char>(tcpclnt->ReceiveBufferSize);
        char * bytess = new char[tcpclnt->ReceiveBufferSize];
        Sleep(500); //Wait for responce 
        do {
            unsigned int k = networkStream->Read(bytes, 0, (int)tcpclnt->ReceiveBufferSize); //Read from google

            for(unsigned int i=0; i<k; i++) {
                bytess[i] = bytes[i];
                if (bytess[i] == 0) bytess[i] = ' '; //Dont terminate the string
                if (bytess[i] < 8) bytess[i] = ' '; //Somethings making the computer beep, and its not 7?!?!
            };
            Console::WriteLine("\n\nAbove packet sent to google. Google Packet Received:\n"+gcnew System::String(bytess)); 

            sendstr->Write(bytes,0,k); //Send it to mozilla

            Console::WriteLine("\n\nAbove packet sent to client..."); 
            //Sleep(1000);

        } while(networkStream->DataAvailable);

        delete [] bytess;
    }
    return;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've tried for hours. (Sorry about the indents nobugz, its fixed now)

Comment: @Per Lundberg It's just you, this is not a school assignment :) Also, It was kinda written 3 years ago, so I hardly think it would matter even if it was lol

Comment: Good point! :D Did you ever manage to solve it?

Comment: @Per Lundberg Unfortunately not, sorry...

Comment: @PerLundberg nice necrocomment :P

Comment: @n00b No need to be mean now :P

Comment: @AStupidNoob Hehe, no worries. ;) I didn't react about the date at all. If I had more time, I might even look into the actual core issue, but unfortunately there's so much other stuff presently...